# Prevent resizing of page window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a WPF app that is set to a specific size for a reason. However the user still has the ability to resize the page. I have set all the maximum page sizes and have achieved three different results, none of which suit my need.

1) The window goes full screen with my app in the top left corner. The rest of the screen is filled with the page background colour.

2) The window goes full screen, page stays central and the rest of the screen is filled with white space.

3) This is the worst solution... The window resizes and shows all the junk i have lying around outside of the page!

All i want to do is prevent someone from changing the window size at all! I am new to wpf and especially new to xaml so want time to learn how to set up auto resizing properly. unfortunately now is not that time (deadlines!).

Thanks

Comment: Probably it could be better to point WPF/.NET version instead of saying you are using VS in tags ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All i want to do is prevent someone from changing the window size at all!

Set the ResizeMode property of the Window to NoResize then:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window13" Height="300" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

...

If you do want the user to be able to resize the window it can never have a fixed size...

Comment: A Page cannot be resized in the first place. It's the parent window that is resized, isn't it?

Comment: I don't have a parent window, I have 5 pages that can all be resized at the moment

Comment: All WPF desktop applications have atleast one top-level window in which the content is drawn. Are you developing an XBAP? It might be an idea to describe what you are currently doing and what you are trying to do if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: When i started the app i was new to wpf to followed a tutorial about creating pages and if I remember correctly I deleted the "main window". I already have 5 pages fully functioning, data logging from an Arduino etc so at this point I need to find a way to prevent the page from resizing without redeveloping.

Comment: @charley You should see navigation bar above the pages - proof that you pages are automatically contained in "something" ;-) I didn't test that possible way can be getting parent's reference and assigning size there - of course before avoiding NullReference exception. But only suggesting...